# make nautilus stop asking for password when mounting disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

My desktop has another hard drive which I intend to use for data storage and the issue is that nautilus always asks for password when trying to mount that drive.

Same when I try and access the drive from the terminal, I get

```
ls: cannot access '/media/luca/storage': No such file or directory
```

So basically, I always need to use sudo to perform file operations on this directory.

Now, is there a way to remove this restriction. How can I auto mount this drive without having to specify my password every time or having to use `sudo` every time I have to access files on this drive?

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not "Programming" related it is probably better asked on the StackExchange site [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @Luca have you found a solution?